# PHP, converted data into a Unix timestamp format

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that looks like this:

```
  <td>Starts</td>
  <td><label for="mm"></label>
    <select name="mm" id="mm">
      <option value="">---</option>
      <option value="01">Jan</option>
      <option value="02">Feb</option>
    </select>
    <label for="dd"></label>
    <select name="dd" id="dd">
   <option value="">--</option>
       <option value="1">01</option>
       <option value="2">02</option>
    </select>
    <label for="yy">
      <input type="text" name="year" id="year" />
    </label></td>
```

It is for people to choose the `month | day | year`. But the field in the database is Unix timestamp format.

Any ideas how can I take this data and converted into a Unix timestamp format for my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll help you, very easy to follow.

[php strotime();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative, in mysql:

```
INSERT ... UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$year-$month-$day') ...
```

once appropriate data sanitization and sql injection prevention's been taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    // convert POST to MySQL date format
    $date_string = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $_POST['year'], $_POST['mm'], $_POST['dd']);
    // if you need it in a UNIX timestamp, do the following
    $unix_timestamp = strtotime($date_string);
}
```

Comment: You've got months going in twice (`mm`).

Comment: Cheers. Fixed now. It's been a long day!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$time = new mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
```

Or ..

```
<?php

$time = new DateTime();
$time->setDate($year, $month, $day);
// set both to 0, otherwise you will get the current time at the given day/month
$time->setTime($hour, $minute);
```

There's a ton of ways to do this in php, spend some time looking over the date/time functions

Answer (score 0):

If the form fields are captured variables $mm, $dd, $yy, then

```
$timestemp = strtotime($yy . '-' . $mm . '-' . $dd);
```

will indeed give you an integer $timestamp (in epoch seconds), as Grigor correctly points out. But in general that may be only half the battle. In your case the Unix timestamp format makes things simple. But depending on your DB (and your associated drivers and DB abstraction layer) you may in some cases need to convert this into a date string of some form. For example, Oracle takes date strings of the form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, which would be generated by

```
$oracle_date_string = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have posted the form back to php, you will end up with your form data in
the special global $_POST.  If your user has selected a date completely, the code snippet
set $unix_ts to the unix timestamp of the date.

```
<?php

  $unix_ts = null;

  // validate date
  if (is_numeric($_POST['dd']) || is_numeric($_POST['mm']) || is_numeric($_POST['year'])) {
    if (($tmp = strtotime($_POST['mm']."/".$_POST['dd']."/".$_POST['year'])) !== false) {  
       $unix_ts = $tmp;
    }
  } else {
    // display error message however you choose
    echo "Date not set<br>";
  }

  if ($unix_ts != null) { 
     // do query
  }

?>
```